# count clicks, and then pass the value to db via php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How would I grab the value generated by the following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#nextBtn a").click(function() {
        $('.slideCount').html(function(i, val) {
            return val * 1 + 1
        });
    });
    $("#prevBtn a").click(function() {
        $('.slideCount').html(function(i, val) {
            return val * 1 - 1
        });
    });
});
```

and then pass that value to this php

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    // get the slide number to set
    if (isset($_POST['txtSlideNbr']))
    {
        $gotoSlideNbr = $_POST['txtSlideNbr'];

        // build our query
        $query = "UPDATE `skdemo`.`demo` SET slide_nbr = " . $gotoSlideNbr . " WHERE demo_name = 'culture';";
        $mysqli->query($query);

        // clear the request
        $gotoSlideNbr = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: And please prevent sql injections with `mysql_real_escape_string`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you want to send this number to the server you make an AJAX request:

```
$.post('script.php', {txtSlideNbr: $('.slideCount').text()}, function(data) {
    proccess server responce if any
});
```

And in your PHP script use:

```
$gotoSlideNbr = (int)$_POST['txtSlideNbr'];
```

This will prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Using `$('.slideCount')` is slow (especially in ie) you should always add a html tag

Comment: Yes, better to add context and cache found element.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the  [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)  function from jquery, it's rather easy to setup, maybe something like this

```
var nrOfClicks = 0;
$("#prevBtn a").click(function() {
    nrOfClicks++; //no need to save it in a div, can just use a variable
    $.post('your_url',{'clicks':nrOfClicks});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it via an ajax call - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ (or use get if you like) - you can send the data you want to send to the URL you define